# HTML style modification not display on Samsung TV

Tags: javascript, android, html, browser, styles

I am javascript beginner and I am stuck with a problem : HTML style modification are not displayed on the browser of the Samsung TV.

I have multiple HTML elements (like below) I want to modify. (Thoses HTML elt comes from  Gentelella)

```html
<div class="widget_summary">
     <div class="w_left w_25">
         <span>0.1.5.2</span>
     </div>
     <div class="w_center w_55">
          <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar bg-green" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 34%;">
                 <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
              </div>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="w_right w_20">
         <span>18k</span>
     </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

I have written this piece of code (embedded in the HTML code :)

```js
var socket = io.connect();
socket.on('histo_tag', function(data) {
      var HistoTagView = document.getElementById("histo_very_cool");
      var HistoTagViewList = HistoTagView.getElementsByClassName("widget_summary");
      for (i = 0; i < HistoTagViewList.length; i++) {
          HistoTagViewLine = HistoTagViewList[i];
              HistoTagViewLine.getElementsByClassName("w_left")[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = data.tagList[i].tag;
              HistoTagViewLine.getElementsByClassName("w_right")[0].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = data.tagList[i].count;
              var withProgressBar = "width: " + Math.floor(data.tagList[i].count * 100 / data.tagsCount) + "%;";
              HistoTagViewLine.getElementsByClassName("progress")[0].getElementsByClassName("progress-bar")[0].style = withProgressBar;
     }
});
```

All the modifications using "innerHTML" field work well on all browsers tested. But modifying dynamically the style of the class "progress-bar" does not work on Samsung browser (works well on firefox and chrome).
I read a lot of post about browser optimization and flushing of style and CSS modification but it did not solve my issue. 
I try to add thing like getComputedStyle() or to request information  such as "offsetTop, offsetLeft, offsetWidth, offsetHeight ..." but without success.

Does anyone knows what could be the reason of this discrepancy between firefox and the samsung web browser

Thank you for your help
Regards